# .htaccess password protection not working with encrypted password

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, password-protection, .htpasswd

I want to make my admin folder protected with htaccess file.Here is my htaccess file

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Title for Protected Site"
AuthUserFile C:/WAMP/www/mysite/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I made htpasswd file and had password encrypted. When i try to access the folder it doesn't accept my password and opens another login, but when i set password to be admin, without encryption, it works.
Does anybody have idea why this is happening?
And if it is important, here is my apache error log

```
AH01617: user admin1: authentication failure for "/mysite/admin/": Password Mismatch
```

Comment: Sidenote: You shouldn't be encrypting, you should be hashing. Unless that's what you meant by "encryption". Those are `two different animals` altogether.

Comment: I used this site http://www.kxs.net/support/htaccess_pw.html is it ok or not? Thanks

Comment: Problem solved then? As for the link you've shown above, that is a hashed password method and most probably uses Apache's `crypt` function to hash it.

Comment: Yeah, solved it, thanks again.